# What do you call the objects you build in the Power Platform?

Tags: powerbi, powerapps, power-automate, power-platform

In Power Apps, you build applications.

In Power Automate, you build flows.

In Power BI, you build reports and dashboards.

If you are writing about all of these things collectively, what is the correct term? Objects? Constructs? Artifacts?

I want to replace the word in italics in the following sentence:

> When creating Power Platform *objects*, our team will follow certain naming conventions.

Answer (score 1):

The common term is "Artifacts".  EG

> Returns a list of Power BI items (such as reports or dashboards) that the specified user has access to.

[Admin - Users GetUser**Artifact**AccessAsAdmin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/admin/users-get-user-artifact-access-as-admin)

> Solutions are the mechanism for implementing ALM; you use them to
> distribute components across environments through export and import. A
> component represents an **artifact** used in your application and
> something that you can potentially customize. Anything that can be
> included in a solution is a component, such as tables, columns, canvas
> and model-driven apps, Power Automate flows, chatbots, charts, and
> plug-ins.
>
> Dataverse stores all the **artifacts**, including solutions.

[Overview of application lifecycle management with Microsoft Power Platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/alm/overview-alm)

Comment: Thanks. But the article also states, "Anything that can be included in a solution is a component", so you COULD say they are components, right? I mean, what's the difference between an artifact and a component?

Comment: There's no bright-line difference, and the terminology isn't 100% consistent.